# Not able to manipulate jQuery on particular situation in onclick event

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-events

I have a situation where when I click on milestones link it unhide a dropdown div with milestones as a heading.

My requirement is when I click inside that div anywhere it should not get hide. it should get hide when I click outside that div only.
Current problem is when I click inside that div it get hide.
Here is the link to the image just for reference.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0zHBJb86qsIUFpWMm1ra3dfc1k/view

```js
$("#headermile").on({//task list in header
  focus:function(){
      $('#mileheader').attr("class", "");
  }, 
  blur:function(){    

    $('#mileheader').click(function (e) {
      if (e.target.id == 'mileheader') {
        $("#mileheader").attr("class","");
      } else {
        $("#mileheader").attr("class","hide");
      }

  });
```

```html
<li class="has-dropdown">
  <a id="headermile" href="#">Milestones </a>
  <div id="mileheader" class="hide">
    <ul class="dropdown settings">
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: add your html code or create example on jsfiddle

Comment: here it is. rest is explained above.

Comment: if possible add full page with css code . so i can create fiddle base on than and provide you example

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0zHBJb86qsIUFpWMm1ra3dfc1k/view

Comment: "... $('#mileheader').click(function (e) { if (e.target.id == 'mileheader') { ...". Do you see how the function triggers only on clicking #mileheader? So how could e.target.id ever be anything other than 'mileheader'. Then you remove the class? Logic is bad here. And there are plenty of other problems with the code.

Comment: you could see the image there . i am not able to do in jsfiddle. not working there

Comment: @TroyThompson yes i thought so. but i am not getting the logic. i am new to jquery

Comment: I don't think "focus" and "blur" should be used here.

Comment: used other logic's as well. none of them worked.

Comment: @TroyThompson ok. so what do u suggest.

Comment: For working with classes in jQuery, try .addClass and .removeClass instead of .attr - or even try .toggleClass

Comment: Don't include PHP in example markup unless your question relates to PHP

Comment: @TroyThompson I have added a image just for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this answer is perfect, just wanted to find a quick solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/troythompson/eLz7ptwf/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#headermile').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#mileheader").removeClass("hide");
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(event) {
        var container = $("#mileheader");
        var button = $("#headermile");
        if (!container.is(event.target) && container.has(event.target).length === 0 && !button.is(event.target)) {
            $("#mileheader").addClass("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

Resource: [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Again, I don't use .attr to try to remove a single class, as it will remove all classes on that element.

Comment: there onclick event is not removing the hide Class.

Comment: Oh you meant if you want to hide the list after you have made it visible, by clicking the link?

Comment: i meant after making it unhide. when i click on that unhidden div it should remain visible unless i click outside that div.

Comment: Tell me about your problem

Comment: on click it do not get unhide. do not remove hide class

Comment: what is it? have any idea ?